# when use vanilla spa i have an error router.js:66 GET http://localhost:3000/views/Category.html 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, dom, single-page-application

I have a project on vanilla JS, I use Webpack. And i change html container contents with spa. I write spa by this article https://medium.com/better-programming/js-vanilla-script-spa-1b29b43ea475 . But I have an error router.js:66 GET http://localhost:3000/views/Category.html 404 (Not Found). what's wrong in my code? my header remains static, only the contents of the main container change. Structure of my project:

```
-src
 -routing
  -route.js
  -router.js
 -views
  -Category.html
  -Page2.html
 -app.js
 -index.html
 -style.css
```

The code:
route.js:

```
'use stict';

let Route = function (name, htmlName, defaultRoute) {
    try {
        if(!name || !htmlName) {
            throw 'error: name and htmlName params are mandatories';
        }
        this.constructor(name, htmlName, defaultRoute);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

Route.prototype = {
    name: undefined,
    htmlName: undefined,
    default: undefined,
    constructor: function (name, htmlName, defaultRoute) {
        this.name = name;
        this.htmlName = htmlName;
        this.default = defaultRoute;
    },
    isActiveRoute: function (hashedPath) {
        return hashedPath.replace('#', '') === this.name; 
    }
}

export default Route;
```

router.js:

```
'use strict';

let Router = function (routes) {
    try {
        if (!routes) {
            throw 'error: routes param is mandatory';
        }
        this.constructor(routes);
        this.init();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);   
    }
}

Router.prototype = {
    routes: undefined,
    rootElem: undefined,
    constructor: function (routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
        this.rootElem = document.getElementById('main');
    },
    init: function () {
        var r = this.routes;
        (function(scope, r) { 
            window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (e) {
                scope.hasChanged(scope, r);
            });
        })(this, r);
        this.hasChanged(this, r);
    },
    hasChanged: function(scope, r){
        if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, length = r.length; i < length; i++) {
                var route = r[i];
                if(route.isActiveRoute(window.location.hash.substr(1))) {
                    scope.goToRoute(route.htmlName);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, length = r.length; i < length; i++) {
                var route = r[i];
                if(route.default) {
                    scope.goToRoute(route.htmlName);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    goToRoute: function (htmlName) {
        (function(scope) { 
            var url = 'views/' + htmlName,
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    scope.rootElem.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
            xhttp.send();
        })(this);
    }
};

export default Router;
```

app.js:

```
import Route from './routing/route.js';
import Router from './routing/router.js';

(function () {
  function init() {
      var router = new Router([
          new Route('Category', 'Category.html', true),
          new Route('ActionSetA', 'ActionSetA.html'),
          new Route('ActionSetB', 'ActionSetB.html'),
          new Route('AnimalSetA', 'AnimalSetA.html'),
          new Route('AnimalSetB', 'AnimalSetB.html'),
          new Route('Clothes', 'Clothes.html'),
          new Route('Emotions', 'Emotions.html'),
      ]);
  }
  init();
}());
```

Here is my webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: false },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'images',
              name: '[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug : true,
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 75
              },
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
                optimizationLevel: 1
              },
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'fonts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new  HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './src/images', to: './images'},
    ]),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems wrong  http://localhost:3000/views/Category.html relative to to your server.

Could be some misconfiguration w.r.t the root path your server is running.

Apart from that it's quite difficult to guess the exact error.  Take a look at relative path from server, check your server/webpack configuration.

Update: Post your webpack update, can you check whether your "dist" folder has the correct folder/paths for views as I suppose your webpack is bundling and deploying your file to "dist" folder.

Comment: Please check the update to answer.  Please check your "dist" folder structure.

Comment: after assembly in the dist folder I do not have a view folder at all. and i have 2 errors Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Rita2/Documents/rs-lang/ritaheav-JS2020Q3/english-for-kids/dist/views/Category.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https at index.html. and views/Category.html:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: You have to deploy the view files.   For now you can manually copy as well.  Also, use an HTTP server to serve pages to avoid CORS issues.